# How to say 'I'm going to start in September. I'm not sure where yet'

Tags: translation

How to say 'I'm going to start in September. I'm not sure where yet.'

If context is needed I'm talking about university.

Answer (score 4):

Another proposal:

> Im September fange ich an [zu studieren], ich weiß bloß noch nicht, wo.

Answer (score 0):

I propose following German translation:

> Ich werde im September beginnen, bin mir jedoch noch nicht sicher, wo genau.

Applicating your Use-Case within this example, it would be:

> Ich werde mein Studium im September beginnen, bin mir jedoch noch
>   nicht sicher, bei welcher Universität das sein wird.